# Planned missing data design not converging

Tags: missing-data, structural-equation-modeling, convergence

I recently ran an experimental study with a planned missing design. Participants were randomly assigned to one of four groups that dictated which portion of a 26-item unidimensional measure they completed. Group 1 completed all 26 items; Group 2 completed items 1-10; Group 3 completed items 11-20; and Group 4 completed items 21-26 (see image below).

[image: x indicates group members completed a given item; NA indicates group members had planned missingness for a given item]

I am interested in comparing measurement parameters (i.e., testing levels of measurement invariance) between the four groups; my idea is that certain groups of items (e.g., those completed by Group 4) change the subjective nature of the construct v. when the items completed by either of Groups 2 or 3 are completed on their own. Specifically, I'd be interesting comparing loadings/intercepts for items completed by Group 2 (and rinse/repeat for Groups 3 and 4) against the same items completed by those in Group 1. So for example, loading values for items 1-10 might differ between Group 1 (who completed the full measure) and Group 2 (who only completed items 1-10).

Anyways, since any missingness on the items for Groups 2, 3, and 4 are deliberately missing at random, I thought I would be able to get full recovery of the missing values (though I'm not interested in these values, actually) in a multi-group CFA model when specifying three dummy coded variables (capturing the four experimental conditions) as auxiliary variables. Using FIML, I can't even get the model ignoring group designation to converge. With MI, I get that much, but then the configural invariance model won't converge.

Any thoughts on what's going wrong here? I can post some output here if that would be diagnostically useful. One possibility I'm considering is, instead of a four-group CFA, I might have better luck running three two-group CFAs, comparing measurement parameters from Group 1 to Group 2, Group 1 to Group 3, and Group 1 to Group 4.

Comment: I'm suprised you can't estimate the model in the whole sample - which obviously is the entire point of the design. Some info on software and code might help.

Comment: What program are you using? Have you tried a different one? Have you tried different starting values?

Comment: I've tried both lavaan (with FIML) via the semTools quick and dirty measurementInvariance command, and MPlus (with MI) the ol' fashioned way. I'll try to post some sample code/output snippets soon.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you're trying to estimate parameters with no information in them. That is, you're asking for the loading of item 1 for group 4, but no one in group 4 did item 1, so it has no idea that that might be.

Comment: "In a multi-group CFA model when specifying three dummy coded variables (capturing the four experimental conditions) as auxiliary variables." I don't think you should be including that (if I've understood correctly - group information is already in the multiple groups, so these will be constant within group).

Comment: Thanks @JeremyMiles I'll give it a try tonight in MI without the dummy variables as auxiliary variables and see how that goes.